# Import SQLite database into MySql with Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

i have tried different ways,
i tried shelljs for running these commands for generating CSV from SQLite DB,

```
shell.exec('sqlite3 /path/to/sqlite-db.db')
shell.exec('.headers on')
shell.exec('.mode csv');
shell.exec('.output /path/to/data.csv');
shell.exec('select * from Table;');
shell.exec('.quit');
```

but it get stuck on 1st command, i need to run all other commands in SQLite cmd.
On terminal these commands working fine.

Or is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the sqlite3 shell, you can pass options instead with Node's built-in [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)-method.

```
const exec = require("child_process").exec

const command = 'sqlite3 -header -csv /path/to/sqlite-db.db "select * from Table;" > /path/to/data.csv'

exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  console.log("stdout: ", stdout)
  console.log("stderr: ", stderr)
})
```

Comment: Work like a charm :)